# Enable/disable microphone in Terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, microphone

I would like to enable or disable the microphone in the Terminal. How can I do it? For example, I use `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo` to disable the webcam and `sudo modprobe uvcvideo` to enable it. Is there a command to to the same thing with the microphone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try

```
amixer set Capture toggle
```

which will toggle the capture of your mic (on/off). You could even connect it to a key (e.g. `XF86AudioMicMute` -if you've got a key that invokes this event), so you would not even have to open a terminal for this.

Comment: I need to add the "-D pulse" option to make it work in my system.Otherwise I would get the "amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Capture',0" error.

Comment: depends how you configured your `/etc/pulse/default.pa` (load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0,0) - but yes, it won't hurt

Comment: Can I do enable/disable directly instead of toggle?

Comment: No, not that I know of.. Alsa (which is below pulse) can only toggle. If my answer solves your problem, I would be happy if you accept it...

Comment: @fedeUbuntu If "Front Left: Capture" also points to your mic, you can use this command (e.g. as an autostart script) to disable the mic when it is on only: `mic="$(amixer | grep "Front Left: Capture" | awk -F' ' '{print $7}' | sed -e "s/\[//" -e "s/\]//")"; if [[ "$mic" == "on" ]]; then amixer sset Capture toggle; fi`

Comment: @kanehekili do you know if this would work for mint?

Comment: Yep, at that time (nearly 3 years ago) it worked for mint. Did you try it out? This is alsa, no pulseaudio or pipewire. So I do not understand your question,

Answer (score 0):

```
wutang@shaolin:~$ gsettings list-recursively | grep mic
org.gnome.desktop.privacy disable-microphone false
org.gnome.shell.overrides dynamic-workspaces true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys mic-mute ['']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys mic-mute-static ['XF86AudioMicMute']
com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys mic-mute 'XF86AudioMicMute'
org.gnome.mutter dynamic-workspaces true
```

```
wutang@shaolin:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy disable-microphone true
```

I actually don't know the effect of this... I am using MATE and a lot of gnome stuff doesn't have any effect on MATE so I cannot confirm. There is usually an org.mate counterpart, but not for this one.